# Как получить целое значение числа в PHP (округление чисел)?

Tags: php

Имеется число 13.21021
Как вывести только 13?

Comment: А если будет 13.99 (или 13.99) - что надо вывести? Если не надо округлять, то `intval($param)` выводит только целую часть

Comment: @RussCoder, под свой ответ подгоняем вопрос?

Comment: @Visman в заголовке была явная ошибка и он не соответсвовал телу вопроса. Единственное к чему можно придраться это `(округление чисел)` - если так хочется, то можете удалить (я решил для поиска так лучше). Но вообщем-то, разве формулировка заголовка не стала понятнее и лучше соответствовать вопросу?

Comment: @RussCoder, в теле вопроса нет ни чего про округление.

Comment: @RussCoder, нда, чего-то я зарапортовался. Извиняюсь.

Answer (score 3):

```
intval(val);
```

в скобках имя переменной с значением

Answer (score 3):

Для округления чисел используйте функцию `float round ( float val [, int precision] )` - она округляет с заданной точностью вверх или вниз в зависимости от числа. Пример:

```
<?php
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Также можно использовать функцию `float ceil ( float value )`. Она округляет дробь в большую сторону до ближайшего целого. Пример:

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(3.0);    // 3
?>
```

Чтобы округлить в меньшую строну используйте `float floor ( float value )`. По сути просто отбрасывает дробную часть. Пример:

```
<?php
echo floor(4.3);   // 4
echo floor(9.999); // 9
echo floor(5.0); // 5
?>
```

Функция `int intval (mixed var [, int base])` позволяет также работать со строками и переводить их в целые числа.

Примеры взяты [отсюда](http://www.php.su/functions/?round), [отсюда](http://www.php.su/functions/?ceil) и [отсюда](http://www.php.su/functions/?floor)

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте принудительное преобразование к типу:

```
$float = (int) 13.91021;
echo $float; //13
```

или

```
$float = 13.21021;
echo (int) $float; //13
```

или

```
echo intval(13.91021); //13
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы откинуть дробную часть числа, можно использовать [манипуляцию с типами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php)

```
$float = 13.21021;
$int = (int) $float;
echo $int;
```

или

```
echo (int) 13.21021;
```

Для вывода целой части числа, так же можно использовать [форматированный вывод](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

```
$num = 13.21021;
echo sprintf('%d попугаев', $num);
```